# Linear Transformation and Image Question

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose T: $R^2->R^2$ is the linear transformation associated to the matrix

A= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{{\sqrt2}}{2}&\frac{{\sqrt2}}{2}\\\frac{-{\sqrt2}}{2}&\frac{{\sqrt2}}{2}\\\end{bmatrix}

The unit square U is the square whose vertices are the points (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), and (0, 1) in the plane $R^2$. Draw the image of U under the linear transformation T. Be sure to include the coordinate axis in your graph.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What's the result if you multiply the matrix with either of these vectors?

Comment: Would you have to find the image based off the matrix first?

Comment: Calculating $A\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$ is precisely finding the image of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$ under $A$.

Comment: It's still not clear to me how I would find the image of the points under A.

Comment: Multiply each of them by $A$, of course.

Comment: So, would you just multiply each point by A and then plot it or is there more to this?

Comment: That's precisely the excercise.

Comment: $A$ just rotates $U$ by $45^o$ about the origin. Is this a homework problem?